# What does "ioyning" mean?

Tags: early-modern-english

From Butter’s news serial, 2<sup>nd</sup> August, 1622:

> ## The certaine Newes
>
> of this preſent Weeke.
>
> ### BROVGHT BY SVNDRY
>
> Poſts from ſeuerall places, but chiefly
>   the progreſſe and arriuall of Count *Mansfield*
>   with the Duke of *Brunſwicke* into *Champeny* in
>   Fʀᴀɴᴄᴇ; and the ***ioyning*** of ſundry of the
>   Princes with them, &c.
>
> ### With the preparation of the French
>
> King to reſiſt him : And what great feare Count
>   Mᴀɴꜱꜰɪᴇʟᴅꜱ vnexpected arriuall hath
>   put all Fʀᴀɴᴄᴇ in, &c.
>
> Out of the best Informations of Letters and
>   other, this ſecond of August 1622.
>
> Lᴏɴᴅᴏɴ,
>   Printed by *I.H.* for *Nathaniel Butter*, and are to
>   be ſold at his ſop at the ſigne of the *Pide Bull*
>   at *S. Auſtins Gate*. 1622.

I’ve transcribed this from p. 197 of Andrew Pettigree’s masterful *The Invention of News: How the world came to know about itself*. I can cope with most of it, but *ioyning* has me puzzled.

Comment: That's "joining".

Comment: That first ‹i›  is now spelled with a ‹j› ... ‹j› is in origin a long (often terminal) form of ‹i› which over time came to be used exclusively for the consonant.

Comment: Heres a [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English#Orthography) that describes several of these orthographic shifts.  Anyone want to merge all these comments into a CW answer?

Comment: "My girl ioyned the circus; now I've ioyned the lonely hearts club"?  I'm assuming that CW means country-western.

Comment: This may be of interest on the history site. 1622 was during the *Thirty-years-War*. Any idea what Count Mansfield and the Duke of Brunswick were doing?

Comment: Related: *[If the letter J is only 400–500 years old, was there a J sound that preceded the design of the letter?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148399/)* ; of related interest, see Cerberus' answer in *[Why should the first person pronoun 'I' always be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7986)*

Comment: Thanks, by the way, for faythfully tranſcribing the long s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JEL already answered the question in the first comment: it means "**joining**". Since it's a question on definition, it probably won't hurt just to cite the dictionary of that era as some source.

In the *[A Dictionarie of the French and English Tongues](http://www.pbm.com/%7Elindahl/cotgrave/558.html)* (1611) by Randle Cotgrave

> ioinct: A ioynt, ioyning, closure; seame
>
> ioindre: To ioyne, couple, … or combine together
>
> Iointe: A ioynt; closure; ioyning; seame

Comment: A valuable resource, not one of ELU's standard references, I'd guess.