# Why are names starting with a "J" common, while words starting with a "J" are uncommon?

Tags: names, alphabet

There's a reason "J" is worth 10 points in Word feud, it's a quite uncommon letter.

> According to Lewand, arranged from most to least common in appearance, the letters are: etaoinshrdlcumwfgypbvkjxqz Lewand's ordering differs slightly from others, such as Cornell University Math Explorer's Project, which produced a table after measuring 40,000 words.

Here's a graph measuring the frequency of "J" in words:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:English_letter_frequency_(alphabetic).svg

Here's a graph measuring the frequency of "J" in names:
http://home.uchicago.edu/~jsfalk/misc/baby_names/images/initial_all.png

Sure, there's a lot of words with a "J" in them (not many relatively), but there's very few words starting with "J". Yet, there's an abundance of names starting with "J". Here, I'll list as many as I can from the top of my head.

Name starting with a J: Jack, Jackie, Jackson, Jill, Janet, Jeremy, Jeremiah, Jake, Jesus, Jacob, Jock, John, Johnny, Jon, Joe, Joel, Janus, Jerry etc.

Words starting with a J: Jar, Jigsaw, Job, Jacked, Jest, Jester, Jeopardize, Jeopardy, Jaguar, Jitters, Jumbo, Jet, and probably some more.

Now, is there a reason for this. Heck, is there even a great difference between the number of names starting with a "J" and words starting with a "J"?

Comment: »Sure, there's a lot of words with a "J" in them (not many relatively), but there's very few words starting with "J".« This is not true. Initial position is by far the most frequent for the letter j in English, for various reasons (most importantly that it most frequently comes from Old French where /ʤ/ was the outcome of Latin initial /j/, while non-initial /j/ was mostly lost instead). Also, several of the names you mention are variants of one name, and at least one (mine, as it happens) is rare enough in English that most are completely unfamiliar with it and don’t know how to pronounce it.

Comment: Your charts use entirely different units and can't be compared. Letter frequency in dictionary words tells you nothing about frequency of usage, and vice versa. For example, the letters Z and X are two of the least common letters in the dictionary, but (in the USA) are frequently seen because of the words EXIT (on highway off-ramps) and pizza (a popular food). You would need to compile a list of unique names in common usage to compare against, so that you're actually comparing the same units.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet _yan-ous_ or _yarn-ous_? Or perhaps _eye-arn-ous_?

Comment: @TripeHound You're getting dangerously close to the word _you-rin-us_ there...

Comment: I've wondered about this exact same question and my thought was that since the Hebrew letter for J is Y (yod) and this letter is considered by some to be the "seed" of the Hebrew alphabet: It is the most basic/fundamental letter and therefore the most commonly used for a name.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

A lot of the "J" names in English are from the Bible and [would have originally been written with an initial I in Latin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148399/if-the-letter-j-is-only-400-500-years-old-was-there-a-j-sound-that-preceded-the), as the letter J did not get started until the Renaissance. In modern transliteration of Hebrew these names are written with an initial Y. For example, "Yeʻhoshua" for Joshua, "Yaʻaqov" for Jacob, or "Yirmeyāhū" for Jeremiah/Jeremy/Jerry. The use of /dʒ/ sound in initial uses of I/J comes from [Early Old French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_French#To_Early_Old_French), through Gallo-Roman influences.

The reason why there are more names than common nouns pronounced this way is that [Old English lacks word-initial /dʒ/](http://tjl.nccu.edu.tw/main/uploads/14.2_.4_4.pdf#page=23) and Latin does not have a lot of word-initial I/J followed by a (second) vowel, while Latinized Hebrew has many names starting with I/J. However, some Old French common nouns do start with initial I/J and these properly became pronounced /dʒ/ and spelled with J: for example *jeopardy*, from *jeu parti*, or *joy* from *joie*.

Comment: Excellent indeed.  It is worth noting, however, that the citation of J names exaggerates the quantity somewhat by including what are variants upon the same name.  Also, what counts as a name in English is rapidly changing with the populations of Anglophone countries.

Comment: "But in the Latin alphabet, Jehovah starts with an I"

Comment: Male names beginning with J: After kings of England?  James, John. Queens: Anne, Elizabeth.

Comment: @Xanne: James and John are both Hebrew names, as Avery mentions. James is יעקב and John is יהונתן. Note that both do start with the letter yod `י`.

Comment: James isn't יעקוב (Yaakov); Jacob is יעקוב. I think James is Greek. @dotancohen

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: James is Old French/English, derived from Yaakov/Jacob through a tortuous process involving B → M in Latin Jacobus → Jacomus (compare Italian *Giacomo*) and then losing C (compare Spanish *Jaime*).

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger The adjective for the reign of James the Ist/VIth is Jacobean, which is a useful clue.

Comment: @dotancohen: the second name in your comment is the Hebrew for Jonathan (Yəhonatan). John [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_(given_name)) comes from  Yohanan (יוֹחָנָן‬).

Comment: Does modern French even feature a hard J sound? I don't think so.

Comment: @Xanne - what's the relevance of Queens Anne and Elizabeth?

Comment: @Tim The relevance is that the most common female English names--e.g., Anne, Elizabeth (and variants), to which we might add Victoria and Mary, are British monarchs, and except for Mary, not Biblical.  So is it only male names that are taken from the Bible? Or is this a questionable premise?

Comment: @Tim: modern French has [dʒ] in loanwords from languges like English and Arabic; e.g. *[gin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/gin)* (from English *gin*) and *[djinn](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/djinn)* (from Arabic *jinn*). It can be analyzed as a cluster composed of the consonants /d/ and /ʒ/,  kind of like the /ts/ used by some English speakers at the start of words like *tsunami* and *tsetse fly* can be analyzed as a cluster of /t/ and /s/.

Comment: @Xanne Elizabeth is a Biblical name (the mother of John the Baptist). Anne isn't, but is derived from Hannah, which is.

Answer (score 15):

A further point is that many of these names are essentially the same name. Your list of 18 names:

> Jack, Jackie, Jackson, Jill, Janet, Jeremy, Jeremiah, Jake, Jesus, Jacob, Jock, John, Johnny, Jon, Joe, Joel, Janus, Jerr

Broken down into 9 groups:

> - John, Johnny, Jon, Jock, Janet
> - Jack, Jackie, Jackson ("son of Jack").  Very closely related to John  (sometimes treated as a diminutive)
> - Jeremy, Jeremiah, Jerr
> - Jake,  Jacob
> - Jill
> - Joe
> - Joel
> - Janus
> - Jesus

I suspect these were selected arbitrarily but they illustrate my point well. Other obvious groups include:

- Julian, Jillian, July, etc. -- you've got *Jill* from this one
- Joseph, Josephine, Jo, etc. -- your *Joe*
- James, Jim, etc. -- related to *Jacob*
- Joshua etc.
- Jennifer etc.

Many of these reached English through multiple routes, the most obvious being *John*/*Jacques*/*Jack*, but this group also relates to the initial I/J shift discussed in other answers as demonstrated by *Ian*/*Iain*/*Ivan* (and even  *Evan* for further confusion).

Comment: James comes from the same root as Jacob, so it fits in one of your existing groups.

Comment: Note also that "Jesus" and "Joshua" also come from the same root.

Comment: @MartinBonner I hadn't really given *Jesus* much though (or *Janus* for that matter), having not come across either  as an *English* name, but that's a good point.

Comment: You haven't shown that names *not* beginning with `J` are not subject to the same proliferation of variants.

Comment: Janus = Ian = John, as far as I know.

Comment: @yo' Etymonline has [John](https://www.etymonline.com/word/john) (etc.) from Hebrew *Yohanan* via Greek, but [Janus](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Janus) from 'Latin Ianus, literally "gate, arched passageway,"' (Janus was patron of such structures). I'll admit to only checking Janus just now as I'd assumed it was something like that

Comment: @user234461 I don't need to.  I don't claim it, and it's not relevant.

Comment: @ChrisH Yes you *do*. If all letters are equally prone to producing variations, then this would not explain why names beginning with J are more relatively common, since the frequency of all other names would have been multiplied by the same factor.

Comment: @user234461 I make no comparison with respect to words/names starting with other letters.  They might as well not exist.  You might have a valid point if you said I hadn't considered whether non-names starting with *J* were subject to the same spread

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out in one of the answers above, the commonest names in English are biblical: John/Johan/Jean/Juan, James/Jacob, Joshua/Jesus, Joseph, Judah/Judas, etc., all of which are Hebrew in origin, and begin with the syllable Jah or Yah, meaning "God".  There are also common names of Roman or Greek origin, like Julius, Jason, Justin, etc.  There are even some names of Germanic origin that begin with J, like Jeffrey.

Comment: The 'j' of 'Jacob', 'Joseph', and 'Judah' is an imperfective verb prefix, unrelated to the 'j' of 'John' and 'Joshua'.

Comment: @ruakh: All the names you mention are from Hebrew, and all start with the letter yod `י` in Hebrew.  Jacob: יעקב, Joseph: יוסף, Judah: יהודה, John: יהונתן, Joshua: יהושוע. They all have literal meanings in Hebrew, and are not just a collection of sounds. In order: "follower", "collector", "Jewish", "God's giving", "salvation".

Comment: @dotancohen: Um, I speak Hebrew, but thanks for trying. (I'm not even sure why you're directing your comment at me; what part of "imperfective verb prefix" made you think "just a collection of sounds"?) By the way, 'John' is actually thought to come from 'Yokhanan' rather than 'Yonatan' (so related to grace rather than giving); and translating 'Judah' as 'Jewish' is anachronistic and backwards (Jewish -- יהודי -- literally means "of/from יהודה").